# Python writing backslash on end of filename

Tags: python, string, utf-8, filenames

I am trying to walk a directory structure (Windows) and the UTF characters are giving me a hassle.  Specifically it is adding a backslash on the end of each filename.

```
import os, sys
f = open('output.txt','wb')
sys.stdout = f
tmp=''.encode('utf-8')
for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('d:\media'):
    # print path to all filenames.
    for filename in filenames:
        tmp=os.path.join(dirname, filename,'\n').encode('utf-8')
        sys.stdout.write(tmp)
```

Without the '\n' the file is one big long string without the added backslash:

```
d:\media\dir.txtd:\media\Audio\Acda en de Munnik - Waltzing Mathilda (live).mp3d:\media\Audio\BalladOfMosquito.mp3\
```

With it I get the following:

```
d:\media\dir.txt\
d:\media\Audio\Acda en de Munnik - Waltzing Mathilda (live).mp3\
d:\media\Audio\BalladOfMosquito.mp3\
```

While I can deal with the extra character in the program I am going to read this into I'd rather know why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the way to redirect to a file and no need to micro-manage encoding.

`.join()` adds a backslash between every element joined, including between `filename` and `\n`.  Let print add the newline as shown below or use `.write(tmp + '\n')`.

```
import os, sys

# Open the file in the encoding you want.
# Use 'with' to automatically close the file.
with open('output.txt','w',encoding='utf8') as f:

    # Use a raw string r'' if you use backslashes in paths to prevent accidental escape codes.
    for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(r'd:\media'):
        for filename in filenames:
            tmp = os.path.join(dirname, filename)

            # print normally adds a newline, so just redirect to a file
            print(tmp,file=f)
```